# MacOS Terminal: Is it possible to create a "drag-and-drop" action via script?

Tags: terminal, drag-and-drop, applescript, shortcut, automator

There are many posts that explain how to drag-and-drop things into an open Terminal window. But what I would like to do is to tell Terminal to drag-and-drop a previously selected directory onto another application like VSCode or Renamer. I have not found any documentation for that. Is it at all possible? And if so, would somebody please point me to a documentation?

UPDATE:
I'd like to clarify my question with what I intend to do:

Pre requisites:

- a "work folder" contains folders and files that shall be renamed
- the renaming is done by an application called "A better finder renamer" (which allows presets)

An "Automator" (MacOS app) action shall imitate these steps:

- the "work folder" is right clicked
- the folder is drag-and-dropped onto the ABFR, which initiates the currently active preset
- other actions via bash (like 'mv ./*/*.* ./') ...

It is the "drag-and-drop" part of the Automator action that presents a riddle for me.

Comment: Are you talking about something more than just scrolling back and dragging selected text?

Comment: I added an example to my question, which should clarify my intensions.

Comment: Drag-and-drop is an OS thing for passing input items to an application.  For Automator, items dropped onto a workflow app get passed to the actions in the workflow.  A **Run AppleScript** action would receive these items via the script via the `input` parameter of the `run` handler.  Trying to involve multiple applications with a single drag-and-drop is going to be problematic.  Have you looked at folder actions?

Answer (score 0):

The **"drag-and-drop"** operation is manual operation. In AppleScript, instead the command to **open** the file or folder is given to the destination application itself.

Second thing to keep in mind. Getting Terminal's current working directory is easy with its **do script "pwd"** command. But the result of the **do script** Terminal command returned to the script is always the window tab, not the result of the **pwd** shell command. One solution is to redirect (remember) the result of pwd in a temporary text file.

```
set tempFolder to (path to temporary items folder from user domain)
set temp to POSIX path of tempFolder & "workingDirectory.txt"

tell application "Terminal" to do script ("pwd > " & temp) in selected tab of window 1

set curDirPosixPath to paragraph 1 of (read file ((tempFolder as text) & "workingDirectory.txt"))
set curDirHFSPath to curDirPosixPath as POSIX file as Unicode text

tell application "Visual Studio Code" to open curDirHFSPath
```

.
NOTE: other possible solution (I don't like) is parsing the text contents of Terminal window after pwd command execution. You can get contents using property **contents** (of selected tab of front window).

Comment: Interesting! I get the current folder like this: 

on run {input, parameters}
 tell application "Finder"
  # Get the current directory, store it in "selDir"
  set selDir to POSIX path of input
  
  move selDir to folder "/Applications/A Better Finder Rename 11.app"
  
 end tell
end run


But I would like to kindly ask you to review my question again, which I edited with an example of what I would like to achieve. Meanwhile ABFR told me that their app does not offer an API that recognises a drag-and-drop. (I guess comments do not allow line breaks...)

Comment: Again, I'm not sure I understand you. Do you want to add "drag-and-drop" functionality to someone else's application (AFBR here)? No, it's called writing an application as a droplet. You cannot edit someone else's application. Ask the app author to do this.

Comment: Are you familiar with Automator? Because than my description of what I want to do should be really totally clear. What else do you need?

Comment: I'm familiar with Automator and not bad, but that's not the point. The thing is, it's not entirely clear what you expect as a result of right-clicking on a folder. It is usually used to start services. Since the application itself is not written as a droplet (it does not contain an "on open" handler), your Automator script must itself issue the "open" command to the application. If you want to create a service in Automator, I'll add the 2nd answer.

Comment: Also, now it's completely unclear what kind of connection "MacOS Terminal" has.

Answer (score 0):

Open Automator, choose create New Document.
Choose create new Quick Action (service).
Set **workflow receives current folders in any application**.
From library Add Run AppleScript action. Edit it contents:

```
on run {input, parameters}
    set curDirHFSPath to (item 1 of input) as text
    tell application "Visual Studio Code" to open curDirHFSPath
end run
```

Save this Quick Action as **service**. Now when right-clicking the folder, opens the context menu, where you can choose and run this service.